# Pass arguments using expanded array built in parts

Tags: bash

I have a script like this:

```
foo=0
bar=0
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
  key=$1
  case $key in 
    --foo)
    foo="$2"
    shift
    ;;
    --bar)
    bar="$2"
    shift
    ;;
  esac
  shift
done
echo $foo
echo $bar
```

I'd like to collect args as an array and then pass together.  If I do this, it works:

```
args=(--foo 1 --bar 2)
script.sh ${args[@]}
```

But, if I build args in pieces, it does not work:

```
args=(--foo 1)
args+=(--bar 2)
script.sh ${args[@]}
```

Results in the message "Invalid Input Argument"

I've also tried:

```
 args=( "${args[@]}" --bar 2)
```

But got the same result.  Thoughts?

Comment: Aside from the fact that you should quote the array expansion (which wouldn't matter given the array values shown), I don't see anything wrong with the code. `script "${args[@]}"`.

Comment: Can you show the *exact* error you are getting?

Comment: The error is literally: "Invalid Input Argument." No other message is given.  I've since worked around this by just building a string, but I'm still stumped on the root cause.

Comment: The message is apparently coming from `script.sh`, so we'd have to see that code to figure out what the problem is. I can't imagine what it would be, though. There isn't anything wrong with the shell code that calls it.

Comment: Using the code at the top as script.sh (adding #!/bin/bash), it works for me using both your examples for creating args. I would try "bash -x script.sh ${args[@]}" and look for clues.